# Express JS routing based on the user names

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am working on a express js project.I have got all my basic routing set up working perfectly. Usually when I want to search a record based on id I do this:

```
    router.route('/sensors_home/:sensor_id')
.get(function (req, res) {
        Sensor.findById(req.params.sensor_id,function(err, sensorInfo) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.send(sensorInfo);
        });
    });
```

This allows me to retrieve the data when I do http://localhost:4000/sesnors_home/45000cbsfdhjbnabfbajhdb

(45000cbsfdhjbnabfbajhdb = Object id from the MongoDB )

Now my goal is to have several users to my application. I have my mongoose schema set up and the mongoDB looks like this :

[image: data]

Here is the issue: I wanna retrieve data corresponding to John Peterson based on his _id that is "John".Instead of doing this http://localhost:4000/sesnors_home/45000cbsfdhjbnabfbajhdb I wanna do something like this http://localhost:4000/sesnors_home/John and retrieve all the data specific to John. I tried various methods but still stuck with this issue. I tried using req.params._id and also some Mongodb queries on the User Collection but still no luck. Please suggest some ideas.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I tried using the following code :

```
router.route('/sensors_home/:id')
.get(function (req, res) {
res.send(_id.toString());
    User.findOne({_id: req.params._id} ,function(err, sensorInfo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.send(sensorInfo);
    });
});
```

This gives me the following error :
    ReferenceError: _id is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
router.route('/sensors_home/:_id')
.get(function (req, res) {
        Sensor.findOne({_id: req.params._id},function(err, sensorInfo) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.send(sensorInfo);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I answered above to your question

Comment: @pink612 your route code looks fine, what does your Sensor schema look like? Do you have a `_id: {type: String, required: true}` attribute in your schema?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are using the first name as the `_id`? I wouldn't typically recommend that since your `_id` is meant to be unique and you will likely have duplicates if you use the first name.

Comment: I have a new answer above

Comment: ahhh that was my mistake. Now I got it working. Thanks!